# if condition within table

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

cshtml file :-

```
@{
    var test = true;
}

<script>
   // $(function () {
        var jqxhr=  $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "",
            global: false,
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {
                return data;

            }
        }).responseText;
    @test = jqxhr;
</script>
<div class="panel panel-info">
<table> 
              @if(@test)
                {
                <tr>
                    //
                </tr>
                }
</table>
</div>
```

hi base on @test value i want to show and hide tr section .
@test in the html part always true .

jqxhr value set to value by ajax response.

how can i get global @test from  jqxhr ?

Comment: `@test` is evaluated server side when the page is served to the client, there's no code that will change that. The ajax request is then performed client side __after__ the table has already been rendered. You'll need to use JavaScript to render the table

Comment: there are model validation , i want to add a specific if condition with this value . how can i do that with javascript

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that . The scope of server side and client side variables are different . C# code executes on server so it doesn't exist in browser from where ajax request happens. Here is how you can accomplish this.

you can return the value of test from server method

```
   $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "",
        global: false,
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            if(data.test){
                $("#row-id").show();}
        }
    });
```

and your html be like this

```
<table>
 <tr id="row-id">
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: tr hide or show not working at <script> tag before ajax call as well